# Stream API in twitter Not responding

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am using `twitter4j Stream API 3.0.3 jar`. I tried to get the User Stream and tweets my code is given below. It is running only not showing any outputs for past 1 hour.

```
public class StreamAPI {

 public static void main(String[] args) {


    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
    cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxx");
    cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxx");
    cb.setOAuthAccessToken("xxx-x");
    cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxxxx");
    cb.setUseSSL(true);

    TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
    RawStreamListener listener = new RawStreamListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(String rawJSON) {
            System.out.println(rawJSON);
        }
        @Override
        public void onException(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    };

    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    twitterStream.sample();

 }
}
```

and when I try to get user, it shows 401 Authentication error

```
static UserStreamListener listener = new UserStreamListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatus(Status status) {
            System.out.println("onStatus @" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {
            System.out.println("Got a status deletion notice id:" + statusDeletionNotice.getStatusId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onDeletionNotice(long directMessageId, long userId) {
            System.out.println("Got a direct message deletion notice id:" + directMessageId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
            System.out.println("Got a track limitation notice:" + numberOfLimitedStatuses);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
            System.out.println("Got scrub_geo event userId:" + userId + " upToStatusId:" + upToStatusId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {
            System.out.println("Got stall warning:" + warning);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFriendList(long[] friendIds) {
            System.out.print("onFriendList");
            for (long friendId : friendIds) {
                System.out.print(" " + friendId);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFavorite(User source, User target, Status favoritedStatus) {
            System.out.println("onFavorite source:@"
                    + source.getScreenName() + " target:@"
                    + target.getScreenName() + " @"
                    + favoritedStatus.getUser().getScreenName() + " - "
                    + favoritedStatus.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnfavorite(User source, User target, Status unfavoritedStatus) {
            System.out.println("onUnFavorite source:@"
                    + source.getScreenName() + " target:@"
                    + target.getScreenName() + " @"
                    + unfavoritedStatus.getUser().getScreenName()
                    + " - " + unfavoritedStatus.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFollow(User source, User followedUser) {
            System.out.println("onFollow source:@"
                    + source.getScreenName() + " target:@"
                    + followedUser.getScreenName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onDirectMessage(DirectMessage directMessage) {
            System.out.println("onDirectMessage text:"
                    + directMessage.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserListMemberAddition(User addedMember, User listOwner, UserList list) {
            System.out.println("onUserListMemberAddition added member:@"
                    + addedMember.getScreenName()
                    + " listOwner:@" + listOwner.getScreenName()
                    + " list:" + list.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserListMemberDeletion(User deletedMember, User listOwner, UserList list) {
            System.out.println("onUserListMemberDeleted deleted member:@"
                    + deletedMember.getScreenName()
                    + " listOwner:@" + listOwner.getScreenName()
                    + " list:" + list.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserListSubscription(User subscriber, User listOwner, UserList list) {
            System.out.println("onUserListSubscribed subscriber:@"
                    + subscriber.getScreenName()
                    + " listOwner:@" + listOwner.getScreenName()
                    + " list:" + list.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserListUnsubscription(User subscriber, User listOwner, UserList list) {
            System.out.println("onUserListUnsubscribed subscriber:@"
                    + subscriber.getScreenName()
                    + " listOwner:@" + listOwner.getScreenName()
                    + " list:" + list.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserListCreation(User listOwner, UserList list) {
            System.out.println("onUserListCreated  listOwner:@"
                    + listOwner.getScreenName()
                    + " list:" + list.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserListUpdate(User listOwner, UserList list) {
            System.out.println("onUserListUpdated  listOwner:@"
                    + listOwner.getScreenName()
                    + " list:" + list.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserListDeletion(User listOwner, UserList list) {
            System.out.println("onUserListDestroyed  listOwner:@"
                    + listOwner.getScreenName()
                    + " list:" + list.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserProfileUpdate(User updatedUser) {
            System.out.println("onUserProfileUpdated user:@" + updatedUser.getScreenName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onBlock(User source, User blockedUser) {
            System.out.println("onBlock source:@" + source.getScreenName()
                    + " target:@" + blockedUser.getScreenName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnblock(User source, User unblockedUser) {
            System.out.println("onUnblock source:@" + source.getScreenName()
                    + " target:@" + unblockedUser.getScreenName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onException(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("onException:" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    };
```

Is anyone can help me to get details about the user, users followers following and tweets in Twitter

Comment: Checkout [*this*](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/335)

Answer (score 1):

The 401 error code indicates that you're not properly authenticated. Are you certain those credentials are correct?

A good way to test that would be to connect to the regular streaming API (rather than a user stream) and seeing if you still get a 401. If you do, then your credentials are incorrect. If it works, then there's a problem with the user stream you're requesting.

Comment: i want to get the details about users tweets friends and followers of a particular user. In normal i am getting all the details but i got reach limit exception. to avoid Rate Limit exception i came for Stream API. User stream not available to public means we need to login with our credentials?

Comment: The rate limit issue just means you need to spread your requests out over time. You can find all relevant information on [the Twitter developers website](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1). You can use the Twitter streaming APIs for this, but you'll use the [Public Streams](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter) (check the follow parameter) instead of [User Streams](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/user), which are by invite only. However, 401 still means "unauthorized," which makes me think you have a problem with your credentials.